# Bootstrap navbar-collapse not dropping on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Since I cant comment yet on someone's thread/question, as I'm new. I would like ask this answered solution by @Tepken Vannkorn.

Solution he provide:

```
[Codepen]: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogyGKg
```

I'm asking because this solution doesn't drop the menu on mobile screen. I would just like to ask how to drop the menu on mobile? What's missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your custom .navbar-brand position it overlaying the button and as a result disabling it's click. Just add this..

```
.navbar-toggle {
     z-index:1;
}
```

http://bootply.com/O1uRKylxXN

Comment: Thank you @Skelly. I actually solved this last night. but still thank you :)